# How to update a textarea's text relative to a checked radio button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu, radio-button

1. A textarea's text will be populated with a dropdown lists selected
   text.
2. A simple radio button list will determine which dropdown list's text should be used.

### CLICK HERE FOR DEMO

The code below creates the desired effect but **does not** make the expected changes when an alternate radio button value is selected.

*Debugging shows checked is not added to radio inputs when a new selection is made.*

**JQUERY**

```
var rbl = $('#rbl input:checked').val();

$('#ddlA1,#ddlB1').change(function () {
    if (rbl = 1) {
        $('#txt').val($('#ddlA1 :selected').text());        
    } else if (rbl = 2) {
        $('#txt').val($('#ddlB1 :selected').text());        
    }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<span id="rbl">
    <input type="radio" id="rbl_0" name="rbl" value="1" /> 1 <br />
    <input type="radio" id="rbl_1" name="rbl" value="2" /> 2 <br />
</span>

<select id="ddlA1">
    <option value="1">A1 A</option>
    <option value="2">A1 B</option>
    <option value="3">A1 C</option>
</select>
<select id="ddlB1">
    <option value="1">B1 A</option>
    <option value="2">B1 B</option>
    <option value="3">B1 C</option>
</select>

<textarea id="txt">LOAD TEXT</textarea>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct but you need to modify some little things ;)

```
$('#ddlA1,#ddlB1').change(function () {
    var rbl = $('#rbl input:checked').val();
    if (rbl == 1) {
        $('#txt').val($('#ddlA1 :selected').text());        
    } else if (rbl == 2) {
        $('#txt').val($('#ddlB1 :selected').text());        
    }
});
```

1. Put **rbl** variable inside the change event
2. Use `==` instead of `=` on your conditionals

http://jsfiddle.net/3kXsX/5/

That's all!

Best Regards,

Comment: I knew I was close, I just couldn't nail it. I tried both those things too; just not together. Many Thanks jc

Answer (score 1):

Something more like this

```
$('#rbl_0, #rbl_1, #ddlA1, #ddlB1').on('change', function() {
    var dropdown = $($('#rbl_0').is(':checked') ? '#ddlA1' : '#ddlB1');
    $('#txt').val(dropdown.find('option:selected').text());
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/3kXsX/4/)

Answer (score 1):

The value of rbl is set once, when that line of code runs, and not updated if the selected radio changes.  Put the `var rbl = ...` line inside the event handler so it checks the radios when a change is made to the dropdown, ie

```
$('#ddlA1,#ddlB1').change(function () {
    var rbl = $('#rbl input:checked').val();
    if (rbl = 1) {
        $('#txt').val($('#ddlA1 :selected').text());        
    } else if (rbl = 2) {
        $('#txt').val($('#ddlB1 :selected').text());        
    }
});
```

Comment: This is helpful thanks. Also needed fix as mentioned by jcgarcia.